# Как получить gifts.get (vk api) пользователя в js?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Работаю с VK API с помощью javascript, использую кроссдоменный запрос с использованием JSONP, как сказано в [документации](https://vk.com/dev/api_requests), пытаюсь получить gifts.get, но постоянно выводит ошибку:
**error_code: 15 error_msg: "Access denied: no access to call this method"**
При получении токена указываю только friends, а также в redirect_uri ссылку на свой сайт.
Openapi включен, доверенный домен есть.
Тип приложения- Standalone-приложение.

Пример моего кода:

```
let script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
script.src = `https://api.vk.com/method/gifts.get?user_id=***&v=5.130&access_token=***&callback=callbackFunc`;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

function callbackFunc (result) {
    console.log (result);
}
```